# Any better way to keep track of goroutine responses?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to get my head around goroutines. I've created a simple program that performs the same search in parallel across multiple search engines. At the moment to keep track of the number of responses, I count the number I've received. It seems a bit amateur though.

Is there a better way of knowing when I've received a response from all of the goroutines in the following code?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

type Query struct {
    url string
    status string
}

func search (url string, out chan Query) {
    fmt.Printf("Fetching URL %s\n", url)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out <- Query{url, resp.Status}
}

func main() {
    searchTerm := "carrot"

    fmt.Println("Hello world! Searching for ", searchTerm)

    searchEngines := []string{
        "http://www.bing.co.uk/?q=",
        "http://www.google.co.uk/?q=",
        "http://www.yahoo.co.uk/?q="}

    out := make(chan Query)

    for i := 0; i < len(searchEngines); i++ {
        go search(searchEngines[i] + searchTerm, out)
    }

    progress := 0

    for {
                    // is there a better way of doing this step?
        if progress >= len(searchEngines) {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Polling...")
        query := <-out
        fmt.Printf("Status from %s was %s\n", query.url, query.status)
        progress++
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify the 2nd for loop a bit, git rid of the progress variable and do the same thing as the first for loop: `for i:=0; i < len(searchEngines); i++`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. For some reason I didn't thank that'd work.

Comment: You could also count down to zero instead of counting up. When waiting on a group of goroutines to finish, this always seems more natural to me. This is not unlike rolling your own wait-group and is simple to understand (not at all 'amateur' in my view).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use `sync.WaitGroup`, there is an example in the [pkg doc](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

```
searchEngines := []string{
    "http://www.bing.co.uk/?q=",
    "http://www.google.co.uk/?q=",
    "http://www.yahoo.co.uk/?q="}
var wg sync.WaitGroup
out := make(chan Query)

for i := 0; i < len(searchEngines); i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func (url string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Printf("Fetching URL %s\n", url)
        resp, err := http.Get(url)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        out <- Query{url, resp.Status}

    }(searchEngines[i] + searchTerm)

}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure there might be a potential race, but I'd still put `wg.Add(1)` before the call to `go` which spawns a goroutine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `wg.Add(1)` should be in front of the goroutine, thanks. I have updated the code.

Comment: Peeking at the source code, `Add()` appears to be thread-safe: http://golang.org/src/pkg/sync/waitgroup.go?s=490:577#L36

Comment: `Add()` should be called before start a goroutine. If we start a goroutine first, and the goroutine can be done in a very short time.Just after start the goroutine, and cpu switch to the goroutine, and if before cpu switch back, the goroutine is done, which means `Done()`(actually `Add(-1)`) is called, in code  `v := atomic.AddInt32(&wg.counter, int32(delta))`, `v` may be less than 0, which will panic.

Comment: Should wg.Done() be 'defer'ed, too?

Comment: `defer wg.Done() ` would be great, however the code example given by godoc doesn't use defer.

Comment: Is this code intended to go in `main` before the final loop? If so, it will deadlock. It's using an unbuffered channel. Each goroutine is blocked on `out <- ...`, waiting for the main thread (the only reader). The main thread is blocked for the goroutines (on `wg.Wait()`) and thus hasn't made it to a `<-out`. Deadlock. It'd work with `make(chan int, len(searchEngines))`. You could then `close(out)` and use a `range` for the final loop. But I liked the original better; IMHO more straightforward and could interleave final processing with waiting for stragglers, where this can not.